# How to automatically change android menuItem data after change sharedpreferences data?

Tags: java, android

I have sharedpreferences on my application & from different fragment and activity, I change that sharedpreferences data. But I have a menuItem with an integer value. So it should be updated when sharedpref data is change/update from any activity.

Example : Its a total amount of money , like if user purchase some products from another activity/fragment the price should be updated.

This screenshot can help you to better understand.
https://prnt.sc/s26pl0

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_bar, menu);
        pointsMenuItem =menu.findItem(R.id.points); 
pointsMenuItem.setTitle(String.valueOf(SaveSharedPreference.getPoints(getApplicationContext())));
        pointsMenuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                pointsMenuItem.setTitle(String.valueOf(SaveSharedPreference.getPoints(getApplicationContext())));
                return false;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When user click on purchase item after(sharedpreferences value update) add `invalidateOptionsMenu()` method

[invalidateOptionsMenu()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html?hl=ko#invalidateOptionsMenu()) will force reload onCreateOptionsMenu

Hope this help you...